# Looking for a phrasal verb to say the hidden reason behind of several issues

Tags: prepositions, american-english, british-english, phrasal-verbs

I'm not even sure whether there is existence of such phrasal verb in English or not. But probably native speakers can help me out with this.

> - All of your friend's problems are **due to** his recent divorce.
> - All of your friend's problems _____ [back/down] to his recent divorce.

**Note:** I guess I saw a phrasal verb with exactly this meaning but unfortunately can't remember it. `Back`/ `down` are just two guesses for the possibly preposition part.

Comment: _Stem from_? _Arise out of_? _Can be traced back to_?

Comment: Nice suggestions, @ColinFine. Appreciate it. The one I'm looking for somehow in some ways sounds like "Come back"or "Return back". I know these 2 are completely out but I guess they can slightly imply that the reasons all together emanates from sth specific. By the way, I know using of those 2 phrasal verbs are just my made-up usages but I mentioned them as a shot in the dark to somehow help you find what I'm looking for as a hint..

Comment: @ColinFine I found sth via google. Please let me know if it sounds good to a native speaker : "..There are so many reasons why—I could write a post on each one of them—but I think all of the reasons come back to a simple fact: this New Yorker fell in love with a country boy.." . The author in the context which exactly seems like mine has used "Come back". https://www.ivyleagueinsecurities.com/aidan-donnelley-rowley-2/2012/10/new-york-or-bust

Comment: Although it's not the most common of phrases, *come back* could certainly be used here. A similar phrase that's sometimes used is *let's* ***circle back*** *to your first point*. (But it wouldn't normally be used in your sentence.)

Comment: Tnx a lot @JasonBassford. I really needed someone to approve this. The one you mention sounds ***meaningful*** in my own language and I really know what it means and how it works! Thanks for sharing it! At the end I'd be completely glad if u suggest me a word instead of what I wrote in bold few line before!

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Let's start over: The main idea which I'm looking for a 'word' in English language  to describe it, actually is: "source of problems". I want to know how we can connect several problems to 'a thing' and claim that that thing is the real hidden source of all those problems? I just think (not yet sure) the sentence "ALL problems come back to Z" is just saying the Z is the source of all those problems. It has created (& supplied) them to keep existing. Please correct me if it sounds wrong to you so far. In the next comment, I'll try to say how 'Due to" can sound similar to the idea

Comment: S Ped I'm sorry it leaves the thread looking strange and I've killed my previous post.

Yes, "All problems *come back to* Z" is fine. It's correct and even if it wasn't, it would still be wholly comprehensible.

Please try to avoid phrases like 'Looking for a phrasal verb interchangeable with “due to”' which will almost never be helpful…

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin you're perfectly right. The title seems horrible. I'll change it as soon as possible. Let me know if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, S Ped. That was a great advance and still, "… to say the hidden reason behind of several issues" will never work, for too many reasons.

Can you find a better translator?

Answer (score 1):

**stem from**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stem) an idiom

stem from (something)
To come, result, or develop from something else.

As in:

> All of your friend's problems stem from his recent divorce.

Answer (score 0):

**Bring on** - Doesn't exactly mean 'due to', but to cause something (usually bad) to happen.

Example sentences:

> - His cold **brought on** an asthma attack.
> - All of his friends problems were **brought on** by his recent divorce.

Answer (score 0):

I think the phrasal verb [***come down to (something)***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/come-down-to) may be what you're looking for. From Collins Dictionary:

> If a problem, decision, or question **comes down to** a particular thing, that thing is the most important factor involved.
>   *The problem comes down to money.
>
>   I think that it comes down to the fact that people do feel very dependent on their automobiles.*

There may be connotations of the underlying reason being *hidden* in the sense that there are other apparent factors "over" the underlying thing that those factors "come down to".

Answer (score 0):

This is really a 'cause and effect' question. [Cause & Effect Words.](https://www.slideshare.net/mralfonso/causeeffect-signal-words)
 There are many ways to connect a root *cause* to a resulting *effect*. One of the most important cautions in using them correctly is to not over generalize.

Making generic & blanket statements can appear you're promoting false conclusions.  *"Of all your friend's problems, getting a divorce seems to effect him the most.*" relates to the specific cause/effect of the divorce.

> All of your friend's problems are due to his recent divorce.

There may be hidden reasons at the source of several issues, and some can have a greater effect than others, but, making a singular statement of cause (*All of your friend's problems are due...*) comes off as either arrogant, or misinformed, or both.